# how do i get the path from askfilename for another function

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

i am unsure on how to get the file path to execute the year function, i have searched online but all i found were static path where mine requires to choose a file using askopenfilename

```
def file1():
    path1 = askopenfilename(initialdir="/desktop/songs", title="select file")
    path_lbl = Label(topframe, text="file path : " + path1).grid(row=0, column=1)
    return path1

def year(x):
   data = pd.read_csv(x)
   for col in data.columns:
       if "year" in col.lower():
           year = list(data[col])
           year.sort(reverse=True)
           rangeyr = year[0] - year[-1]
           print rangeyr
       else:
           print "there is no data for year"
print data

base = Tk()
base.geometry("500x250")
base.title("data reader")

Button(topframe, text="add path", command=file1).grid(row=0, column=0)

Button(bottomframe, text="confirm", command=year(path1)).grid(row=10, column=3)

base.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a tkinter variable `StringVar` to store your path:

```
from Tkinter import *

def file1():
    path1 = askopenfilename(title="select file")
    Label(base, textvariable=v).grid(row=0, column=1)
    v.set("file path : " + path1)

def year():
    print v.get()[12:]
    #data = pd.read_csv(v.get()[12:])...

base = Tk()
v = StringVar()
base.geometry("500x250")
base.title("data reader")

Button(base, text="add path", command=file1).grid(row=0, column=0)

Button(base, text="confirm", command=year).grid(row=1, column=0)

base.mainloop()
```